# Unresolved External Error - How to know what libraries are mising ? VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How do I know what libraries are required when I get such errors ? Is there a strategy on to determine the library I need given the error ? **Note that this is a library problem** Below is just one of the 90+ unresolved errors.

```
Error   74  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __cdecl pcl::search::Search<struct pcl::PointXYZRGB>::getSortedResults(void)" (?getSortedResults@?$Search@UPointXYZRGB@pcl@@@search@pcl@@UEAA_NXZ)  c:\Users\Haziq\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PCL-Tutorial\PCL-Tutorial\main.obj PCL-Tutorial
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: There is an implicit assumption that when you use #include in your code then you also know what you are including.  Or if you use somebody else's code that used the #include then they'll tell you what you need to link.  The linker error message gives plenty of hints as well, you are using the Point Cloud Library.

Comment: Yeah thanks ! Problem is there are 4 separate folders with tons of libraries in them. The tutorial posted on the PCL website uses cmake which I have no experience with. So i'm just gonna have to try to include all the libraries until I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write code to check all installed .a and .so libraries on the system, generating the symbol table for each one, and GREPping the output for the symbol(s) that remain undefined.